# React/JavaScript: Flatten nested array while renaming properties in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested array in state that I need to flatten.  For example:

```
nestedArray = [{ name: 'Dog', obj: {fname:'Bigdog'}, sec{time: 15}},
              { name: 'Bird', obj:{fname: Bigbird'}, sec:{time: 23}}]
```

But I need a flat array that looks like this:

```
newArray =[ {id: 1, content: Bigdog, start: 15},
             {id:2, content: Bigbird, start: 23}
```

Comment: `content: Bigdog` Is that a new variable? Have you made any attempt to write code to accomplish this yourself yet? Please post what you've tried

Comment: where do you get `id` from?

Comment: id would be new. For each entry count +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map over the input array to create the expected objects.

```js
nestedArray = [{
    name: 'Dog',
    obj: {
        fname: 'Bigdog'
    },
    sec: {
        time: 15
    }
}, {
    name: 'Bird',
    obj: {
        fname: 'Bigbird'
    },
    sec: {
        time: 23
    }
}]

console.log(nestedArray.map((ob, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: ob.obj.fname, start: ob.sec.time})))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map it:

```
nestedArray.map((a,idx) => ({ id: idx, content: a.obj.fname, start: a.sec.time}))
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response.  Out of all three I tried the one with the check mark. However, I still upvoted the others because they were helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use some destruction and build new objects.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'Dog', obj: { fname: 'Bigdog' }, sec: { time: 15 } }, { name: 'Bird', obj: { fname: 'Bigbird' }, sec: { time: 23 } }],
    result = array.map(({ obj: { fname: content }, sec: { time: start } }, i) =>
        ({ id: i + 1, content, start })
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the following approach [using `map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), to achieve this:

```
var newArray = nestedArray.map(function(item, index) {

    return {
        id : (index + 1),
        content : item.obj.fname,
        start : item.obj.sec.time
    }
})
```

The basic idea here is to "map" each item from `nestedArray` to the new `newArray` array.

When an item is mapped, we transform the item into the "shape" that you want items in the resulting `newArray` to be - the `content` and `start` fields are therefore based on data we extract from each `obj` of the `nestedArray` array.

Note that this assumes `id` is based on the current `index + 1` of the item in `nestedArray` being processed.

For more information on `.map()`, [see this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Hope this helps!